# Многоуровневые списки в Лиспе

Tags: lisp

Здравствуйте! Задача такая - вычислить число атомов на верхнем уровне списка.
Если можно - пока просто теоритически объясните как происходит деление на уровни в списках, потому что примеров хороших я пока не нашла..
Например список ( (1 2) 3 4 (7 5))

Comment: Верхний это какой? Что за уровни?

Comment: Первый уровень - это то что на первом уровне вложенности (самые внешние скобки). В данном случае на первом уровне находятся: список (1 2), атомы 3, 4 и список (7 5). На втором уровне находятся элементы вложенных списков: атомы 1, 2, 7, 5. Ну и т.д.

Comment: все, спасибо, теперь понятно

Answer (score 1):

Как это работает в Elisp. Примеры приведены при использовании Emacs 25.2.

```
ELISP> (length '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
4 (#o4, #x4, ?\C-d)
```

Длина списка, где каждый элемен - это атом или другой список.

```
ELISP> (atom 1)
t
ELISP> (atom '(1 2))
nil
ELISP> (atom "hello world")
t
```

Проверка на "атомарность".

```
ELISP> (cons '(1 2) '(3 4 (5 6)))
((1 2)
 3 4
 (5 6))
```

cons -   собирает два списка в один.

```
ELISP> (car '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
(1 2)
ELISP> (cdr '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
(3 4
   (5 6))
```

car -  возвращает голову списка (первый элемен)

cdr - вернен хвост (все кроме первого)

Собираем искомую функцию, возвращающую количество атомов списка:

```
ELISP> (defun count-all-atoms(form)
         "Return recursevly all number of atoms in a FORM"
(cond 
   ((null form) 0)
   ((atom form) 1)
   (t (+ (count-all-atoms (car form))
          (count-all-atoms (cdr form))))))
count-all-atoms
ELISP> (count-all-atoms '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
6 (#o6, #x6, ?\C-f)
```

Ищем только по первому вложению:

```
ELISP> (defun count-atoms(form)
         "Return number of atoms from the first levle of FORM"
  (cond
    ((null form) 0)
    (t (+ (cond
            ((atom (car form)) 1)
            (t 0))
          (count-atoms (cdr form))))))
count-atoms
ELISP> (count-atoms '((1 2) 3 4 (5 6)))
2 (#o2, #x2, ?\C-b)
```